# How to add the static resources in Spring-boot by annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Besides the pre-determined folders (such as /static/), is there any way to configure Spring Boot **(not by XML)** to specify the locations of static resources?

For example, starting from this [guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/), we add another image file, test1.jpg, as our static resource.

Here is the final directory structure:

```
└── src
   └── main
       └── java
           └── hello
               └── Application.java 
               └── GreetingController.java
       └── resources
           └── templates
               └── greeting.html
           └── assets
               └── img
                   └── test1.jpg
```

We did not change any java code from this [guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) , but only add one additional line in greeting.html :

```
<img src="test1.jpg" />
```

Nevertheless, our greeting.html still cannot find test1.jpg.

Could someone give us some suggestions?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `@Bean` of type `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and set the paths yourself, e.g.

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/assets/img";
    }
```

Why not just use the defaults though?